# Can we have a central kibana without elasticsearch?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kibana, google-kubernetes-engine, elastic-stack

In GCP kubernetes I have 2 clusters of different region, in both I have deployed Elasticsearch,Kibana operator & logs pushed by filebeat runs in a container along with application container in same pod.

I have plan to deploy ElasticSearch, Kibana operator in every cluster, thus looking for feasibility to have a centralized kibana without an Elasticsearch for that centralized kibana as I dont want to spend money buying storage for centralized elasticsearch to store all other region cluster's logs.

**Expectation:** will have a centralized kibana and I will configure other kibana's IP & password in it and my query should go over the cluster's kibana fetch/return data to central kibana.

Is it possible? any alternates suggestions please..

Comment: I would instead have centralised ELK stack itself instead of just having kibana. I'm not sure if kibana can talk to multiple end points to read data.

Answer (score 2):

Kibana needs elastic search for storing configuration data. So you may add one small elastic node with centralized Kibana.

Then connect to external elastic search servers. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/working-remote-clusters.html